# Google Maps - Get List of Nearby Addresses

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm looking for a way to get a list of nearby address when doing reverse geocoding. Right now it only gives me the closest rooftop, but I wanted something like a list of nearby addresses.

It would also be nice if I can specify the radius to search for so if I made like `/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.732172,-73.994325&radius=1mile`

I would get something like:

```
[
    {
        "address": "20 East 9th",
        "distance": "0 feet",
        ......
    },
    {
        "address": "21 East 9th",
        "distance": "10 feet",
        ......
    }
    ....
]
```

Or something I can transform into that.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the Google Places API?

Comment: @geocodezip I want a list of address of any kind (including houses), not just restaurants

Comment: The places API includes more than just restaurants.  Might not be what you want, but it is the only possibility (at least from Google).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by addresses but you can get a list of nearby places using the google places api (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search).

Here is an example request from the google places api documentation:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food
```

or you can use the google maps radar search if you're looking for all places near a point 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search

Comment: I'm not looking for places (restaurants), I want all types of nearby addresses

Comment: you can use the google places radar search https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search